# Set paragraph text with javascript on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

Basically all I want to do is set the text of a paragraph using JavaScript/jQuery on page load. This is for a simple Kendo UI app.

Can anyone please give me a method of doing this?

I know this is probably a noob question, but I'm semi inexperienced with JavaScript/jQuery.

This is what I've already tried, but it doesn't seem to be working...

```
<script type="">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#mac001OEE").val("0%");
        });
```

This code has been placed in the head of the HTML page.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 34):

Please try `.text()` good read here: http://api.jquery.com/text/

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/FyVzF/13/ **or** for your specific example using id please see here http://jsfiddle.net/FyVzF/14/

hope this helps!

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("p").text('test test Rambo');
});
```

**HTML**

```
<p> </p>
```

Comment: @Tats-Link is missing for the demo

Answer (score 11):

Try this only for a particular paragraph with the id "idname":

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("p#idname").text('test test Rambo');
});
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mac001OEE").html("0%");

});
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mac001OEE").text("0%");

});
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of `.val()` use `.text()` or `.html()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p").text('saeed');
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p").html('saeed');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For non-input elements you should use `html` or `text` methods:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mac001OEE").html("0%");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to set the text of a `p` element, use `text()`:

```
$("#mac001OEE").text("0%");
```

`val()` is used on elements which have a `value` attribute, such as `input`, `select` and `textarea`.